# Java - ExecutorService for fixed number of tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, executor

I would like to achieve the following behaviour using `ExecutorService` from Java. I have a large number of tasks to complete which can all be done in parallel. I would like to schedule from my main thread only N tasks at the time in the following manner:

- if the number of active tasks is < N => schedule new task (executor service does that already)
- else, block on the main thread until one of the tasks is done => pretty much the same as storing N first tasks in the queue and then dequeing the first and calling get() on it)

Is there a way to tweak the ExecutorService to do as stated above?

Comment: isn't that a fixed threadpool executor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a ThreadPoolExecutor of N threads, constructed with a SynchronousQueue. Each time you'll submit a task to the thread pool, the main thread will be blocked by the synchronous queue until a thread from the pool takes the task from the queue.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the synchronous queue would block the main thread?

Comment: Read its javadoc. It's all explained there.

Comment: Note that your explanation of why you want to block the main thread is not really pertinent. In the end, the main thread will continue its execution, but there will still be N files being processed by the thread pool. Why don't you submit everything to a fixed thread pool, and await the returned futures?

Comment: So store all 400K futures in memory and process one by one? I am calling a method on an object, that does not know how many results will be stored, so it does not know whn to start processing the results

Comment: Yes, or use an ExecutorCompletionService, in order to be able to process the files ass soon as they've been processed by the executor, or combine these approaches if you want to limit the number of futures in memory.

Comment: that's fine, if you knwo when to process them -> I cannot simply submit one file for processing and then immediately process that future, as I would be reverting to single threaded model. And the class itself does not know when the last ile will be submitted...

Comment: You could post-process the files in another thread. If you don't, then I don't see how you could avoid storing all the futures in memory, since the main thread couldn't start processing the futures before it has submitted all the tasks.

Comment: But you said that the main thread had to use files created or modified by the submitted tasks, so you need a way to wait for all the tasks to be finished before proceeding with the main thread, right? So, just waiting for the last submission is not sufficient, since there will still be N tasks being executed. So you need to have some completion service waiting for the last task to be finished before letting the main thread restart. So either you await every future in your main thread, or you use a completion service that decrements a CountDownLatch each time a task is completed for example.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Constructing a ThreadPoolExecutor with a SynchronousQueue will not make the main thread pause. When the thread pool is busy it will reject tasks immediately instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could submit N tasks to an ExecutorCompletionService, then in a loop:

```
Future<?> f = executor.take(); //blocks until one task completes
executor.submit(nextTask());
```

By doing that, you make sure that no more that N tasks are queued in the executor at the same time.